# Kotlin enum generic function

Tags: kotlin, generics, enums

I need a Kotlin function to return an enum value from a string when given a default value for the enum.

Each enum class has a valueOf() method, but I am after a generic that works for any given enum class.

For a sample enum I can do:

```
enum class Example {
    first,
    second,
    third ;

    companion object {  // Note same exact code also works if not in companion object
        fun valueOrDefault(value: String, default: Example) = try {
            valueOf(value)
        } catch (e: IllegalStateException) {
            default
        }
    }
}
```

The challenge is how to make a generic. I have code that needs to do this for any given enum class.

The problem is I cannot see how to write a generic version of the function.

So far I have:

```
fun <T: Enum<Any>>valueOrDefault(value: String, default: T): T = try {
     valueOf(value) as T
} catch (e: IllegalStateException) {
    default
}
```

But no matter what combination I use can cannot get access to the `valueOf()` method.  I tried making the function and extension function for T , but that did not help.  It could be that the syntax of `Enum<Any>` is incorrect... but any insight appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an intrinsic function that Kotlin provides for getting a value of an arbitrary `enum class` by name: [`enumValueOf<T>(name: String)`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/enum-value-of.html).

As it needs to get the type information at compile time from each of the call sites in order to find the corresponding enum class, it can only be applied to [`reified` type parameters in `inline` functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#reified-type-parameters), so you will have to add those modifiers to your function.

If it fails, it will throw an `IllegalArgumentException` (on the JVM) or `IllegalStateException` (with Kotlin/JS as of now), so to return the default value, you have to catch the exception.

The resulting code would be:

```
inline fun <reified T: Enum<T>> valueOrDefault(value: String, default: T): T = try {
    enumValueOf(value)
} catch (e: IllegalArgumentException) {
    default
} catch (e: IllegalStateException) {
    default 
}
```

<sup>[(runnable demo)](https://play.kotlinlang.org/#eyJ2ZXJzaW9uIjoiMS40LjEwIiwicGxhdGZvcm0iOiJqYXZhIiwiYXJncyI6IiIsImpzQ29kZSI6IiIsIm5vbmVNYXJrZXJzIjp0cnVlLCJ0aGVtZSI6ImlkZWEiLCJjb2RlIjoiZnVuIG1haW4oKSB7XG4gICAgcHJpbnRsbih2YWx1ZU9yRGVmYXVsdChcIkNcIiwgTXlFbnVtLkEpKVxufVxuXG5lbnVtIGNsYXNzIE15RW51bSB7XG4gICAgQSwgQlxufVxuXG5pbmxpbmUgZnVuIDxyZWlmaWVkIFQ6IEVudW08Kj4+IHZhbHVlT3JEZWZhdWx0KHZhbHVlOiBTdHJpbmcsIGRlZmF1bHQ6IFQpOiBUID0gdHJ5IHtcbiAgICBlbnVtVmFsdWVPZih2YWx1ZSlcbn0gY2F0Y2ggKGU6IElsbGVnYWxBcmd1bWVudEV4Y2VwdGlvbikge1xuICAgIGRlZmF1bHRcbn1cbiJ9)</sup>

<sup>The `T: Enum<T>` type parameter is how an `enum class`es are restricted: they all implement the `Enum` interface providing the self type as the type argument.</sup>

There's another intrinsic function that gets all enum values from a reified type parameter representing an `enum class`: [`enumValues`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/enum-values.html)

Another way that doesn't require `reified` type parameters but can only work with Kotlin/JVM but not other platforms is to get the `default`'s `javaClass.enumConstants` and find the value by name.

Comment: Generally a very good answer. Thank you, the key was 'enumValue'.  However, one problem, when I tried it, did not go, even in JVM code.  Surprising since you had a demo.  Turns out that with either 1.3.X kotlin, or with Kotlin JS, it needs a change to work.  From `<reified T: Enum<*>>` to `<reified T: Enum<T>>`. Note this still works with JVM version 1.4.  Also, with the JS version, the exception is not IllegalArgumentException as it is with JVM, but IllegalStateException, so I am testing for both so code is multiplatform.   Please make some notes in your answer so I can give it the 'tick'